# google aiy vision kit compiler: get output node from tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, google-aiy

I'm trying to deploy to a google aiy vision kit v2 a custom model trained with Keras API in Tensorflow,when compiling the model from a `.pb` Tensorflow file with the vision kit compiler i get:

```
output node named "<output node>" does not appear in the graph.
```

My question is,  how can i get from tensorboard the output node passed to the compiler in the parameter `--output_tensor_names`?

I already tried the values returned by:

```
keras_model.outputs[0].op.name    # returns final_output/Sigmoid
keras_model.outputs[0].name    # returns final_output/Sigmoid:0
```

and `final_output`, which is the name given to the last layer in keras.

But none of these worked, how can i see the correct expected node in tensorboard?